# How can I read the directory contents on a remote server with PHP?

Tags: php, directory

I have a url, `http://www.mysite.com/images` and the `images` directory allows Directory Listings. How can I get the files in that directory with PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example if you need to read the images over HTTP and the server is Apache:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/images';

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$count = preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a><\/td>/i', $html, $files);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    echo "File: " . $files[1][$i] . "<br />\n";
}

?>
```

If it is the same server you are running your PHP on, you can use opendir() and readdir().

Comment: HTML parsing via regex? BOOO, I say.

Comment: It's not "HTML", it's just some well-known text-structure (that looks like HTML, by accident). Regex is excellent for this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but just to get me into the swing of using this forum I thought I'd add my view. I found the following happened (referring to the original answer to use regex.

My html turned out to be formatted like this:

```
<td>
<a href="bricks.php">bricks.php</a>
</td>
```

So I ended up using this:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<a href=\"([^\"?\/]+)">[^<]*<\/a>/i', $html, $files);
```

I wanted to use the following (which tested ok in the online generator testers, but it failed to find a match in the php code):

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<td>(?:[\w\n\f])<a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a>(?:[\w\n\f])<\/td>/i', $html, $files);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to take urls from listing. (No you can't use DOMDOCUMENT as it's not a valid HTML)

Answer (score 1):

You need FTP access (an FTP account to that URL).  If you have this, then you can log into the server with FTP and use:

```
opendir()
```

and

```
readdir()
```

to accomplish what you are trying to do.

---

If you do not have access to the server, you will need to scrape the site's HTML, and it gets more complex -> so I can let somebody else tackle that one... but google search "scrape html site" or something similar, there are plenty of pre-written functions that can do similar things.

i.e.
http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial

http://www.bradino.com/php/screen-scraping/

Answer (score 0):

// tho a late-comer, this one seems a bit more reader-friendly if not faster

```
$url = 'http://whatevasite/images/';
$no_html = strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));
$arr = explode('Parent Directory', $no_html);
$files = trim($arr[1]);
$files = explode("\n ", $files);
var_dump($files);
```