# get file list from remote dir and return it as an array

Tags: php, javascript, html

**The project:** I'm trying to get a list of image files from the NOAA server (it's open and allowed). The file names are semi-random based on time stamp. I need to return that dir list to an array.

The code snippet from this post works.
 [HERE >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437480/how-can-i-read-the-directory-contents-on-a-remote-server-with-php)

It looks like this **after I hard code the $url:**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/NCR/JAX/';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$count = preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a><\/td>/i', $html, $files);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    echo "File: " . $files[1][$i] . "<br />\n";
}
?>

call the  function getimages (NCR, JAX) ;
function getimages (ncr_or_nzt, the_site_name) {
    var filelist =new array (); 
    var filelist = 'http://mysite.com/mypath/getimages.php?ncr_or_nzt&the_site_name';
}
```

Then I only need the 4 **most recent file names** from the dir

**Last, I need the var **filelist [ ]** array available outside the 'function getimages' so I can asign it to an 'img.src' tag elsewhere in the html.**

Wish I could describe it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, this worked.. thanks all

in the html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" 
function loadjquery () {
$.ajax({
    "url": "ajaxV6.php",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "success": function( data, status, xhr ){
        alert("this is returned from the php ->>" + data[1] );
        noaafilelist = ( data[1] ); //<< assign to global var

    }
});
```

}

and..

```
function showResult (){
            alert('this is global ->>' + noaafilelist );
}
```

and.. in the PHP..
.. at very end, print

```
print json_encode($files[1]);
```

and to make it global for the rest of the html file add:

```
var noaafilelist; // out side the function
```

I'm sure this will seem clunky after a few months.. but right now it's at least working.

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest first...**

```
var filelist = new Array(); // declare array outside of function first

function getimages(ncr_or_nzt, the_site_name) {
    filelist.push('http://mysite.com/mypath/getimages.php?ncr_or_nzt&the_site_name');
}

// filelist is now available outside of the function
```

**Passing arguments to PHP...**

`$argv` is an array of command line arguments. You should probably test for the nuber, etc. but to get you started...

```
$url = sprintf('http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/%s/%s/', $argv[0], $argv[1]);
```

Also, if you're using PHP as a CLI script, put `#!/usr/bin/php` (or the location of PHP on your OS) and make the script executable. On a Linux machine you would do a `sudo chmod +x [filename]`, and then you can execute with `.\[filename]`.

**Get first four images only...**

Lastly, to get only the four most recent images, you can do something like the following...

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a><\/td>/i', $html, $files);

// turn files array upside down, most recent first and vice versa
$files = array_reverse($files);

if ($count >= 4) {
    $count = 4;
}
```

Or...

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a><\/td>/i', $html, $files);

// turn files array upside down, most recent first and vice versa
$files = array_reverse($files);

// slice off the files we want
$files = array_slice($files[1], 0, 4);
```

And then...

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("File: %s<br/>\n", $file);
}
```

*Is there anything else you need..?*

Comment: wow..! I will try that right now.. re" is there anything else you need?...in the last section "Get FIRST four images only".. what I think I need is the LAST four images, not the first four.. I need the four MOST RECENT images (they add a new one about every six minutes.)

Comment: I think I put something in the wrong place..I changed the 2nd line in the php to "$url = 'http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/%s/%s/', $argv[0], $argv[1]);" .. and now it throws an error.. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in getimages.php on line 2"

Comment: Yeah, d'ya see the semicolon after the single quote in the URL? Take it out.

Comment: well, I got the 2nd line fixed.. no error.. but the return is not fetching the file name..it seems to be fetching the path letter by letter.. i.e. alert (filelist [0]); =h.. then alert (filelist [1]); =t.. then alert (filelist [2]); = t.. then alert (filelist [3]); = p ..etc.. must be something small wrong but I don't see it..

Comment: the file name should be something more like : JAX_20130127_1727_NCR.gif

Comment: Taking another look at your JavaScript, I realized it didn't make sense. You need to `push` the sites onto the array. See my revision. Your `filelist` var is a string, so trying to use it as an array pulls one char at a time.

Comment: also.. filelist = new array();  throws an error code of "uncaught reference Error":array is not defined

Comment: Use `filelist = new Array();`. The word 'array' should be capitalized.

Comment: not sure where the new "for each.." should go. in the php or the html?.. I need the files returned as an array.. not echo'd to the screen.. sorry for being so dense.. it seems really close.

Comment: It replaces your `for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) { echo "File: " . $files[1][$i] . "<br />\n"; }`. You should probably just return the array instead, but that's where I can't help anymore as I don't know what you do with it. :)

Comment: re: "You should probably just return the array instead" yes!.. that's what I need.. within the 'function getimages" if I do "alert(filelist[0]); as a test, I need to see "JAX_20130127_1727_NCR.gif" .. I can take from there.. but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Is it too early to ask for some green check goodness? Or am I being too presumptious? :)

Comment: I'm certain that you provided all the right information but I've just not assembled it correctly .. I will certainly "green check" it as soon as I can get the JAX_20130127_1727_NCR.gif into a var that I can use elsewhere in the app .. In my original request for "help" I said "Last, I need the var filelist [ ] array available outside the 'function getimages' so I can asign it to an 'img.src' tag elsewhere in the html.".. but I'm not there yet. thank you in any case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23461/discussion-between-user1985512-and-gordon-freeman)